# Prevent Running PHP From URL

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript game which when the user is completed runs a command similar to:

'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=save&score=100&user=Username'

Which saves the score (100 in this example) for the user 'Username'

I want to prevent this from being run directly from the URL so users can simply save a score without playing the game. So the php can only be run from within the javascript.

Edit: The admin-ajax.php has a defined function called 'save_score()' which resides in functions.php.

Comment: Sounds like you need to switch from using GET to POST.  GET makes use of the url. POST does not. However, be aware that JavaScript runs client side -- so the user can manipulate values in JavaScript.

Comment: Even if you switch to a POST, anyone who plays your game can view the JavaScript that's powering it and find and deconstruct the call to your php script. On the server side, you could do a few things like: Reject CORs requests, verify the requests "referrer" is the address of your game, and/or enforce a custom user-agent string.

Comment: There's no way you can be completely certain that an incoming request to your PHP script has come from your JavaScript game, and isn't being spoofed.  However, there are some simple things you can do to make it more difficult, like switching to POST and using an authenticated token

Comment: Yeah I guess there's no way to completely prevent this but I'll try switching to POST.